# Kubernetes kubelet security issue

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, amazon-eks, kubernetes-security

We are using EKS that is integrated with Vault using kubernetes as 'auth-backend' for Vault. One of the security flaw we see is that, if someone has access to kubelet certs, they can impersonate kubelet and hence can acquire secret for a service account that a pod has been mapped to (service account which already has Vault creds access as per the Vault Role defined) and authenticate itself with Vault and get the DB credentials from Vault. Is there a way to mitigate this.Basically how can we mitigate the risk of someone impersonating kubelet.

Comment: A kubernetes cluster should always be in a locked down state meaning no one, not even an admin should SSH into the cluster. Proper cluster configs (RBAC enabled) should be setup and only those should be distributed to all the users.